# Editor Preferences missing in TFS

Tags: tfs

I would like to be able to Toggle Word Wrap in pull requests.

We have version 16.131.28106.2 (Team Foundation Server 2018 Update 3) which we are hosting on site.

According to the documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releasenotes/tfs2018-update2)

> To manage these settings, click on the editor preferences gear in the pull request editor or diff view. In the Files view, select the User Preferences option on the right-click menu.

[image]

But I have no gear:
[image]

Does editor prefererences have to be enabled somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to click on a file in the tree pane, it doesn't show up if you click on a folder or the root.  If you click on a file the gear shows up.  Unfortunately, enabling "Code Folding" or "Word Wrap" doesn't seem to do anything at all.  UPDATE: after a while it started working.  Huh.